# Python select for blocking

Tags: python, sockets, select

I'm writting a server code to listen information from a socket, but when I press the letter P I have to send back to the client a "Message". Here is what I have done so far:

```
import select
import Queue
import socket
import time
import sys
import msvcrt
from msvcrt import getch

n = 0
HOST = ''
PORT = 2323

servsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
servsock.bind((HOST, PORT))
servsock.listen(5)
servsock.setblocking(0)

inputs = [servsock]
outputs = []
message_queues = {}

while 1:
    (sread, swrite, serr) =  select.select(inputs, outputs, []);
    for sock in sread:
        if  sock is servsock:
            (newsock, address) = servsock.accept()
            newsock.setblocking(0)
            print "New connection: ", address
            inputs.append(newsock)
            newsock.send("You are connected")
            outputs.append(newsock)

        else:
            recv_msg = sock.recv(100)
            if recv_msg == "":
                (host, port) = sock.getpeername()
                print "Client %s:%s disconnected" % (host,port)
                sock.close()
                inputs.remove(sock)
                outputs.remove(sock)
            else:
                (host, port) = sock.getpeername()
                print "Client %s:%s sent: %s "% (host,port,recv_msg)           

    for sock in swrite:
        while msvcrt.kbhit():
            if msvcrt.getch() == "p":
                sock.send("Message")
```

But looks like the select reaches the swrite, enters there, but then it does not iterates anymore between sread and swrite. If I press "1" anytime, indeed it will send to the socket a "Message" but it never returns to the sread!
What I just need is to read for incomming messages all the time, and when I press the key P to send a "Message", without blocking the rest of the program.

Can you please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect it to go into the read segment?  What is it supposed to read that it isn't? In other words, how do you know it's not getting there when it's supposed to?  If there are no new connections or data being sent to this, the select will never trigger for reading because there's no reading to do.

This code isn't good, though, as you will be spamming the swrite section because your sockets are (almost) always writeable.  You should only be selecting for write when you want to write something.  If you check your CPU, you will be almost guaranteed 100% utilization.

Ideally, you would find a library which would allow you to add keyboard input as a selectable object so you could look for keyboard hits in your select.  However, I don't know if there is a way to do that in python.

Comment: Actually I have dessigned a "Client" program which is sending to this Server information constantly, so if the select is working as I expect and reads again, it should come up with that information. In fact, I can be sure the sread part is nor working properly because I'm not receiving anything.

The idea behind the swrite part is that, when I press P, the program knows it has to send back to the client that "Message".

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the timeout on the select.select, so it is blocking there.  Here's an example that waits for upto 100ms (0.1seconds):

```
(sread, swrite, serr) =  select.select(inputs, outputs, [], 0.1);
```